# Sorting array with respect to two properties

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, hash-map

I'm sorting with respect to `Width` and `Length`. However, `Width` has the significance precedence, so `Length` is only vital if `Width` is exactly equal (both are integers). The comparison method I've implemented as shown below. Is this a neat trick with doubling the most significant value's comparer or is there a better way?

```
  List<Thing> things = thingsDictionary.Select(thing 
    => thing.Value).ToList();
  things.Sort((first, second)
    => 2 * first.Width.CompareTo(second.Width)
       + first.Length.CompareTo(second.Length));
```

Comment: Wait, is `Width` a property or a method? I'm confused by `first.Width(second.Width)`

Comment: Pleas avoid variable names such as `things`, `thingsDictionary` and `first`. This doesn't give any meaning to the variable. Plus, give the datastructure for the class `Thing`. This looks like pseudo-code and is not fit for reviewing!

Comment: @dcastro My bad. Please view edit.

Comment: @Heslacher This **is** real code. But the computer I'm on has no connection to the Internet so I had to retype it by hand. Forgot to bring over *CompareTo(...)*. My sloppiness. Now it's on-topic again.   :)

Comment: @Abbas This **is** production code. I understand how you figure but in this case, it **actually** is like this. We have a class called *Thing* with properties *Length* and *Width* (the only difference is that those are in a foreign language, which makes it even harder to get a sense of).

Comment: I'm voting to reopen based on your assertion that this is production code and your correction of the broken code, but I believe you would get a better review if you included more of the surrounding code for context. Also, be prepared to get bashed pretty hard for having a class named `Thing`.....

Comment: I have reopened this question, reluctantly. Code Review questions are not a place for 'hot-fixing' your code based on feedback. Editing the code in your question after an answer is given means that all the answers become out-of-sync with the question. Bad planning on your part (posting a bad question) should not force other people to update their answers, or make their answers wrong. Please see [what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765). In this case, @dcastro has been kind enough to update his answer, but this should not be expected.

Comment: @RubberDuck Agreed. At the client, the insurance covers events and things. I can't post production code **and** make it "look good".   :)

Comment: @rolfl I get the point and agree with the necessity of keeping a high level on the question. You might keep in mind that the system where the code resides isn't connected to the Internet and I had to retype the whole thing, which led to a mistake, which I corrected and apologized for. There wasn't any answer given at the time of my correction, as far I could see, so let's relax and be glad that it's resolved. You **do** have a good point generally speaking, of course. I'll try to be more careful in the future. Still, no idea why the question got downvoted...   :)

Comment: @rolfl Given the update of the question, the old part of the answer is obsolete. Should I remove that part (or ask the replier to do that)?

Comment: @KonradViltersten I just did that, no worries :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like your implementation relies on `Width.CompareTo(second.Width)` to return either 1, 0, or -1.

This assumption is wrong. If `first.Length` is greater than `second.Length`, `CompareTo` is allowed to return 9999, or 1, or 500. These could very well screw up your additions.

Sure, the *current* [.NET implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int32.cs,cdfcead877b41ccc) returns either 1, 0, or -1, but that's an implementation detail. Furthermore, other C# implementations or even future version of .NET may return other values.

Also, *tricks* reduce readability.

A correct implementation would be:

```
things.Sort((first, second)
    => {
        var widthComparison = first.Width.CompareTo(second.Width);
        if(widthComparison == 0)
            return widthComparison;
        else return first.Length.CompareTo(second.Length);
    });
```

But instead of fixing your implementation, I would suggest using LINQ's [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534966(v=vs.100).aspx) and [`ThenBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.thenby(v=vs.95).aspx) instead. It doesn't seem like you need to sort the list in-place, so there's no need to reinvent the wheel.

```
List<Thing> things = thingsDictionary.Select(thing => thing.Value)
                                     .OrderBy(x => x.Width)
                                     .ThenBy(x => x.Length)
                                     .ToList();
```

Comment: The implementation was sloppily typed by me. Sorry. I forgot to type in *CompareTo* (I'm on two computers and dev environment has no Internet access). Nevertheless, your suggestion is still spot on, so +1. Given that I updated my question with the missing method, we need to update your reply accordingly, to make sense, before accepting it. Who's doing that - you or I?   :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten I've updated my answer :) glad it helped

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion by dcastro to use LINQ here is good. But if, for some reason, you wanted to keep using `List.Sort()`, it means you have write a custom `IComparer` or `Comparison`.

And you can use [the ComparerExtensions library](https://github.com/jehugaleahsa/comparerextensions) to write the comparer using a more readable, LINQ-like syntax:

```
things.Sort(KeyComparer<Thing>.OrderBy(thing => thing.Width).ThenBy(thing => thing.Length));
```

Comment: I don't think NuGet is an option in my case. I won't be able to access the servers. Also, the *ThenBy* works really well, as it seems. +1 for alternative solution, though.

Comment: @KonradViltersten You can still download the DLL or the source code on another computer and transfer it on a flash drive, assuming that's allowed.

Comment: Care to take a guess on whether it's allowed? This particular customer is a bit extreme (had bad experience before and went too far preventing the repetition). There's no DVD-drive and all the USB/FW ports are glued, locked or removed. Which is a female dog because I can't connect a mouse nor keyboard. Luckily, it's a side project and I only need to do it infrequently.   :)

Comment: A *bit* extreme? Holy cow